# Azure PIM for VM Admin Role

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure PIM and exploring its capabilities.
I have a use case in hand wherein I need to make the VM Admin role requestable via PIM. I am trying to build a custom role so that I can attach a single VM in the role as part of scope but am unable to do so. All the VMs that are present in the subscription/resource group are getting attached to the role which is not the requirement.
So, in short, is it possible to create a custom role with scope defined for a single VM only though there are multiple VM's in the subscription and(or) resource group.

Comment: Hi All, Any pointers?

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You could do that with Az PowerShell cmdlet [New-AzRoleDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroledefinition?view=azps-5.4.0).

Please refer to second example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles-powershell#create-a-custom-role-with-the-psroledefinition-object). (Modify `$subs = '/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VM_name}'`)

```
$role = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.Authorization.PSRoleDefinition]::new()
$role.Name = 'Virtual Machine Operator 2'
$role.Description = 'Can monitor and restart virtual machines.'
$role.IsCustom = $true
$perms = 'Microsoft.Storage/*/read','Microsoft.Network/*/read','Microsoft.Compute/*/read'
$perms += 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action','Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/restart/action'
$perms += 'Microsoft.Authorization/*/read'
$perms += 'Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/read'
$perms += 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read'
$perms += 'Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*','Microsoft.Support/*'
$role.Actions = $perms
$role.NotActions = (Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name 'Virtual Machine Contributor').NotActions
$subs = '/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VM_name}'
$role.AssignableScopes = $subs
New-AzRoleDefinition -Role $role
```

Then you can assign this custom role to users in **Azure Portal -> this VM -> Access control (IAM)**.

You can also use cmdlet [New-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-5.4.0) to assign the role.

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId {objectID of the user} -RoleDefinitionName 'Virtual Machine Operator 2' -Scope /subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VM_name}
```

Make sure the value of `-Scope` here is the same as `AssignableScopes` in the first script.

**BTW:**

In fact, I don't think it's necessary to attach a single VM in the role as part of scope.

When you assign the role to a user, you need to specify the scope as the second script above shown. You can create the custom role with all the VMs that are present in the subscription/resource group getting attached. When you assign the role, you specify only one particular VM as the scope. Then the user can only manage this VM, but not any other VMs.